# Potential leak Analyzer result wont go away

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, llvm, analyzer

I have this method, and the analyzer tells me there is a potential leak of the `itemsArray` mutable array. I have added the corresponding `release` at the end of the method, but still the analyzer result remains.

```
- (void)addCategory:(NSString*)category {
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    if (category) {
        [[APP_DELEGATE itemsDictionary] setObject:itemsArray forKey:category];  
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [itemsArray release];
}
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not raise any issues with the analyzer:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *itemsDictionary;

- (void)addCategory:(NSString*)category {
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    if (category) {
        [itemsDictionary setObject:itemsArray forKey:category];  
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [itemsArray release];
}
```

Can you post the exact wording (or perhaps a screenshot) of the warning you see?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try putting [itemsArray release] before the line of [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];